# 95% of Blender functions stopped working?

Tags: interface

I was working on a blender project, and then I decided to open a new blender file to try something else out as a separate project, and then all of a sudden hardly anything works on Blender when I click on tabs/buttons. The only things that work is I can select all of my object, move my object, rotate my view and add new objects.

However I can't go into edit mode or any other mode pressing tab or using mouse. Literally nothing works when I click on anything else, however when I hover buttons, it still highlights but I just can't click it.

I've tried reinstalling blender, restarting PC, updating all my drivers and blender program and PC, but most of my blender still doesn't work.

This issue also applies to all of my other blender files as well as when I open a new blender file. Any thoughts?

Here's a link to one of my projects  with the problem.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DNNos79W1Toha9QjP_s_DDElYTmSpCvd/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That file works fine her (Blender 3.2.2, Windows 10).

Comment: Nice animation. The blend file works for me. There might be something messed up in your user preferences. They are stored in your home directory and don't get deleted when you reinstall Blender. You can start Blender with the factory settings when you start "blender_factory_startup.cmd" in the Blender directory.